# Keeping early commit history when preparing for initial release

Tags: git

Lets say I start a new project and track it in git. I add `Feature 1`, and then commit. I then add `Feature 2` and commit. Finally, after adding `Feature 3`, I decide that I want to release this project. I create a third commit with the message `Initial Release`. I rename the current `master` branch to `dev`. Now I want to create a NEW master branch whose history shows ONLY the `Initial Release` commit.

I could do

```sh
git checkout dev
git rebase -i --root
```

That would get me down to a single commit, from which point it's easy to start rebasing onto my new `master` branch. But what if I want to keep my first two commits on the `dev` branch? I want to be able to look back at them to see how I built the application, but I want the `master` branch to have a clean history that STARTS with the `Initial Release` commit.

Is this possible? Or does my `master` branch have to show every common ancestor all the way back to the first commit?

Comment: I suggest reading about tags and the `--first-parent` option to `log`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, the goal of this is that when I push `master` upstream, it won't have any of the early commits.

Comment: If you have a new master branch with a single revision.... how do you get to keep dev in relation to this new master branch?... my question would rather be: What do you want dev to be in relation to the new master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce any commit graph you want with any contents you want.  Start it off this way:

```
git checkout -B dev               # dev is the old master, you already did this
git branch -f master $(           # switch master to a new commit I'm, about to build ...
        git commit-tree -m 'Initial release' dev:  # with the wanted content & message
        )
```

which gets you from

```
A---B---C---D    master
```

to

```
A---B---C---D    dev

           D'    master
```

where D' has D's contents.

If you don't need to merge back from master into dev, if it's a publication-only release history branch, you're done. Next time, add `-p master` to the commit-tree to record the ancestry.

If you do want to merge back from any development work, you need to additionally provide a merge base from the master history to the dev history, I'd probably do this by rewriting the `dev` tip to include the new ancestor, after making the new master tip,

```
git checkout -B dev $(  # add a parent, keep existing message and tree:
        git show -s --pretty=%B dev | git commit-tree -p dev^ -p master dev:
        )
```

producing

```
...C---D   dev
      /
    D'     master
```

As always, when refactoring things like this it can save some heartache if you keep track of who's got refs to existing commits and branch names, the first step above doesn't abandon anything, but any other repo that has an `origin/master` ref to your history will see it replaced by this completely new history.  That's not a bad surprise for anybody unless, of course, it is. The second step, giving yourself a mergeback base so people can push patches and stuff, does abandon the existing `dev` (the original `master`) tip, also not a problem if you do this as a prepublication ritual so nobody else ever sees the old single-parent version.

Comment: It's answers like this that make me realize how much there is to learn about git! Thanks! I'm glad to have this answer to reference, and I may go down this rabbit hole in the future, but it's overkill for this project. For now I just ended up creating an additional branch with my early commits, deleting `master`, squashing `dev` back to a single commit, then merging `dev` into `master`. What I take from this answer is that unless those early commits are really valuable, it's not worth trying to keep them, at least not as part of an active branch.

Comment: Yah, your method left you with a not-strictly-needed extra merge commit and went through some gyrations stringing together convenience commands to counteract the bits you didn't want, but other than that extra merge commit you got exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
git checkout feature3 # or the revision that says "initial release"
git checkout -b new-master --orphan # new master, orphan, everything will be in index, no parent revisions
git commit -m "Initial release"
# if you like the result
git branch -f master # point master where we are
git checkout master
git branch -d new-master
```

Comment: Interesting! So in this case, you ALWAYS have a single commit on the master branch. Not quite what I was looking for, but I feel like it could come in handy at some point.

Answer (score 0):

(on master branch):

```
git checkout -b dev    #create new dev branch at master
git branch -D master   #delete master branch
git checkout --orphan master   #create new orphan master branch and switch to it
git commit             #commit current changes (which should be the "Initial Release")
```

Now you have a single commit on master, and all the original commits on dev

Comment: If you do this, you can't merge without the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag and manually fixing conflicts. Accomplishes the primary goal, but at the expense of mucking up the relationship between the `dev` and `master` branches (which seems to be the crux of this problem).

Comment: You are correct, if you intend to merge between dev and master in the future, this is not a good solution. Unfortunately, I do not know a way to hide early commits from the master branch and yet keep a good merge relationship with the dev branch. With this solution, no more development should be done on the dev branch. It's there for history only...so you can keep track of the history you don't want visible on master.